# SQL: Inserting into a (dynamic) lookup table

Tags: sql, oracle

Most articles about lookup tables deal with its creation, initial population and use (for looking up: id-->value).

My question is about dynamic updating (inserting new values) of the lookup table, as new data is stored in data tables.

For example, we have a table of persons, and one attribute (column) of it is `city of residency`. Many persons would have the same value, so it makes sense to use a lookup table for it. As the list of cities that would appear is not known beforehand, the lookup table is initially empty.

To clarify, the value(s) of `city` is/are:

- not know beforehand (we don't know what customer might contact us tomorrow)
- there is no "list of all possible cities" (real life cities come and go, get renamed etc)
- many persons will share the same value
- initially, there will be a few different values (up to 10), later more (but not very much, a few hundred)
  Also, the expected number of person objects will be thousands if not millions.

So the basic algorithm is (pseudocode):

```
procedure insertPerson(name,age,city)
{
    cityId := lookup(city);
    if cityId == null
        cityId := insertIntoLookupTableAndReturnId(city);

    INSERT INTO person_table VALUES (name,age,cityId);
}
```

What is a good lookup table organization for this problem? What exact code to use?
The goal is high performance of person insertion (whether the city is already in the lookup table or not).

General answers are welcome and Oracle 11g would be great.

Note: This is about an OLTP scenario. New persons are inserted in real time. There is no known list of persons that can be used for initialization of the lookup table.

Comment: Do not interleave dimension table load with fact load. Just load your dimensions first an then proceed with fact tables. In that way when loading facts you know that dimensions exist.

Comment: @arturro "the list of cities that would appear is not known beforehand" I changed the wording a bit to emphasize it more.

Answer (score 1):

Your basic approach appears to be OK except for one small change I would do: The function `lookup(city)` will search for the city and return the ID and, if the city is not found, will insert a new record and return its ID. This way, you are further encapsulating the management of the lookup table (cities). As such, your code would become:

```
procedure insertPerson(name,age,city)
{
    INSERT INTO person_table VALUES (name,age,lookup(city));
}
```

One additional thing you may consider is to create a **VIEW** that would be used to query for persons' information, including the name of the city.

Comment: The query part is off topic for this question. Also, as mentioned at the beginning, that is well covered in other lookup related articles.

Comment: You mean the suggestion about creating a **VIEW**? If yes, that was also my guess but though it would worth mentioning anyway.

Comment: (yes, the VIES part) No problem, just trying to prevent the discussion going off topic.

Answer (score 0):

After some testing, the best performance (least block accesses) I could find was with an index organized table as the lookup table and the below SQL for inserting data.

```
create table citylookup (key number primary key, city varchar2(100)) organization index;
create unique index cltx1 on citylookup(city);
create sequence lookupkeys;

create sequence datakeys;

create table data (x number primary key, k number references citylookup(key) not null);

-- "Rome" is the city we try to insert
insert all 
  when oldkey is null then -- if the city is not in the lookup yet
    into citylookup values (lookupkeys.nextval, 'Rome') -- then insert it
  -- finally, insert the data row with the correct lookup key
  when 1=1 then into data values (datakeys.nextval,nvl(oldkey, lookupkeys.nextval)) 
  select (select key from citylookup where city='Rome') as oldkey from dual;
```

Result: 6+2 blocks for city-exists case, 10+2 for city-doesn't-exists yet (as reported by *SQL*Plus* with `set autotrace on`: first value is *db block gets*, the second *consistent gets*).

Alternatively, as suggested by Dudu Markovitz, the lookup table could cached in the application and in the hit case just perform an simple INSERT into the DATA table, which then costs only 6+1 block accesses (for the above test case). Here the problem is keeping the cached lookup table in sync with the database and possible other instances of the server application.

PS: The above INSERT ALL command "wastes" a sequence value from the `lookupkeys` sequence on each run, even if no new city is inserted into the lookup table. It is an additional exercise to solve that.